# Use one CMD window to control/input into other CMD windows?

Tags: windows, batch, powershell, cmd.exe

Is there a way with batch/powershell to have a parent console input into a child console, eg entering "echo hello" in the parent console would cause "echo hello" to be entered into the child console.

Doing this with only one child console makes no sense, however with more child consoles it would cut back on time entering the same command into multiple consoles.

Comment: Not easily. In theory you could build a vbscript that does it and use cscript to launch the vbscript with parameters that send them to another cmd window, but its all manual, not automatic.

Comment: Seems kind of confusing per your wording but you could redirect the output from cmd console 1 to a file and then pipe that into a command from the other commands in the other consoles I suppose. You'd likely need to provide the script with whatever logic you are running to know for certain if this is possible in your case but what you actually need and what you say you need may be two different things. There are many people here that know batch scripts and PowerShell well so providing your script work would help you get more attention potentially.

Comment: I've been working this over and I would need to code a console application in c++.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean as in does that mean you give up on this question and don't have anything to add to it with an [edit] (which would mean you should just delete it), or do you have some detail to add to show what work you've already put into this task from your side? It's is still not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish to if you can [edit] and clarify and potentially show me where you're stuck, etc. I may be able to help you—I have ideas, I just don't know if they'd work for you or not until you clarify a bit.